# Porting to google cloud DNS but can't find ALIAS record

Tags: google-cloud-dns

We have a domain coolcats.com and need to add ALIAS coolcats.com to pixie.porkbun.com where our website is hosted.  I don't see how to add an ALIAS record in google cloud DNS?  Can I do it via an api perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, **Cloud DNS at the moment doesn't support ALIAS records**. Have a loom at the [Supported DNS record types](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#supported_dns_record_types).

You can file a `Feature Request` at Google Public Issue Tracker under [this component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187241&template=1162897). Also, as a workaround, you can set up your own DNS server inside VM like [PowerDNS](https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/guides/alias.html).

Comment: What about doing CNAME @domain.com -> pixie.porkbun.comm.    That seems to work just fine as an alias now.  Doing it with blank didn't work but adding the @ symbol seems to work.

Comment: Could be a solutions if it works for you. I'll be able to check it tomorrow.

Comment: oh, I don't think that worked after all.  I just routed the name to the ip instead :(.

Comment: I'd recommend you to file a Feature Request in that case.